# Create multistage docker file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, devops, docker-machine

I have 2 different docker files (production and test environment). I want to build a single multistage docker file with these 2 dockerfiles.

First dockerfile as below:

```
FROM wildfly:17.0.0

USER jboss

RUN mkdir /opt/wildfly/install && mkdir /opt/wildfly/install/config

COPY --chown=jboss:jboss  install /opt/wildfly/install
COPY --chown=jboss:jboss install.sh /opt/wildfly/bin

RUN mkdir -p $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/data/datastorage

CMD ["/opt/wildfly/bin/install.sh"]
```

Second dockerfile as below:

```
FROM wildfly:17.0.0

USER jboss

RUN mkdir /opt/wildfly/install && mkdir /opt/wildfly/install/config

COPY --chown=jboss:jboss  ./install /opt/wildfly/install
COPY --chown=jboss:jboss install.sh /opt/wildfly/bin

RUN rm /opt/wildfly/install/wildfly-scripts/Setup.cli
RUN mv /opt/wildfly/install/wildfly-scripts/SetupforTest.cli /opt/wildfly/install/wildfly-scripts/Setup.cli

RUN rm /opt/wildfly/install/wildfly-scripts/Properties.properties
RUN mv /opt/wildfly/install/wildfly-scripts/Properties-test.properties /opt/wildfly/install/wildfly-scripts/Properties.properties

RUN mkdir -p $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/data/datastorage

CMD ["/opt/wildfly/bin/install.sh"]
```

**Question** How to create a multistage docker file for these 2 docker files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want the output of `docker build` to be?  The second seems like a superset of the first, and usually a multistage Dockerfile ultimately creates only one image out at the end.  (Consider using `docker run -v` to inject alternate config files at runtime rather than building a different image per environment.)

Comment: @DavidMaze .... of course the output of docker build to be want to be image successfully build and it is nothing to do with the docker run for me. Simply i want to make a multistage file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do requires a multi-stage build. Instead, what you may want to do is use a custom base image (for dev) which would be your first code block and use that base image for production.

If the first image was tagged as `shanmukh/wildfly:dev`:

```
FROM shanmukh/wildfly:dev

USER jboss

RUN rm /opt/wildfly/install/wildfly-scripts/Setup.cli
RUN mv /opt/wildfly/install/wildfly-scripts/SetupforTest.cli /opt/wildfly/install/wildfly-scripts/Setup.cli

RUN rm /opt/wildfly/install/wildfly-scripts/Properties.properties
RUN mv /opt/wildfly/install/wildfly-scripts/Properties-test.properties /opt/wildfly/install/wildfly-scripts/Properties.properties
```

This could be tagged as `shanmukh/wildfly:prod`.

---

The reason why I don't think you want a multi-stage build is because you mentioned you are trying to handle two environments (test and production).

Even if you did want to say use a multi-stage build for production, from what I can see, there is no reason to. If your initial build stage included installing build dependencies such as a compiler, copying code and building it, then it'd be efficient to use a multi-stage build as the final image would not include the initial dependencies (such as the compiler and other potential dangerous dev tools) or any unneeded build artifacts that were produced.

Hope this helps.